# Reading Overlapping Columns with R read.fwf

Tags: r, fixed-width

I am trying to read a fixed width text file using the read.fwf function. I am having difficulty though because a couple of my variables overlap. For example I may have the following line in my text file:

> 1A...

Variable one has a width of 1 and so it refers to "1" in the line. Variable 2 however has a width of 2 and refers to "1A". Looking at the read.fwf documentation it looks like you can specify widths, but this would make my second variable "A." instead of "1A". I was wondering if there is a way to use read.fwf. and specify start and end positions for the variables rather than just widths.

Note: this is similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172793/read-multiples-of-same-columns-in-a-fixed-width-file) but that discussion seemed to turn more towards a Stata package. I am not working with Stata in my example, I simply have start and end positions specified in a metadata file.

Comment: But the approach would be similar. Use `substr` as indicated in the "sqldf" approach.

Comment: So there is no way to do this simply with read.fwf? Sorry just want to be clear, I am fairly new to R and just want to make sure

Comment: nope. But it's not too difficult to do if you have start and end positions. Usually that's just a matter of using `cumsum` and `diff` and related tools to get the right positions. A good read is [the blog post](https://sites.google.com/site/timriffepersonal/DemogBlog/newformetrickforworkingwithbigishdatainr) that I had linked to in my answer at the question your found.

Comment: Ahh good call, sorry I missed that

Comment: Also see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18726054/1270695) where I used the example from `read.fwf` to show how I constructed the "sqldf" command.

Comment: Can you explain how distinct variables can overlap? This sounds like a recipe for disaster.  Frankly, I would suggest that "overlap" really means "data are encoded inside strings"  and that your should read in the maximal string lengths and then extract substring data with regex tools.  --- Guess I'm really saying the same thing that other commenters have said.

Comment: I nominate @AnandaMahto for the title of resident `R_Data-Munging_Guru`, a title owned on Rhelp by the indefatigable Jim Holtman. No disrespect is intended for others who could legitimately compete for that title including G.Grothendeick and AnthonyDAmico.

Comment: @BondedDust  Technically, I believe Jim is the Data Mung**er** Guru :-)